# How do I convert three dictionaries that are related to each other into a JSON file?

Tags: c#, json

I have three dictionaries:

1. Projects
2. Seasons
3. Episodes

Each project has a list of seasons and each season can have one or more episodes.

It's basically a tree. This is what the API will provide.

I'm not sure how to do this but I was thinking something like this:

```
public class ProjectList
{
    public List<Project> Projects
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Project
{
    public string ProjectTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ProjectLink
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Season> Seasons
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Seasons
{
    public string SeasonTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string SeasonLink
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Episodes> Episodes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Episodes
{
    public string EpisodeTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string EpisodeLink
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine and probably the most straight forward and common way you'll see data with these relationships organized. If you're using json.NET converting it to json is as simple as;

```
  string responseBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProjectListInstance);
```

The default serializer will handle everything for you returning the full complex object. `JsonConvert` is in the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace and is imo the best tool for serializing and deserializing json in C#.

Comment: Also, if you don't like the lengthy property declaration syntax, try C#'s "auto-implemented properties" syntax, detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: As of .NET 4.5, the builtin libraries are probably a more convenient choice.

Comment: @millimoose you know I thought I read that .NET was just going to include json.NET and now I've been seeing questions with these new libraries... That was just a terrible choice by Microsoft. I'm obviously not going to use their libraries when all the code I've been working on the past two years uses json.NET.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal That's a sensible choice. Less so for the OP who does not have two years of legacy code around.

Comment: @millimoose Hah, when I saw it taking up multiple lines, it didn't quite register in my head that way, and I thought it was just pseudocode.

Comment: @millimoose Agreed. Although I think json.NET is better than the new libraries and will continue putting it in new projects despite it adding another 3rd party dependency.

Comment: I'd also mention the [ScriptIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) and/or [JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) on related fields to prevent serializing any object that points to the same or other objects that point back to the original (forgot what that is called, it just fell out of my mind!)

Comment: @ErikPhilips well the problem is that it could throw a circular reference exception. There is another setting to handle that too. I'd have to do some digging to find it though...

Comment: @ErikPhilips btw they're just called "Circular Object References"

Comment: That's it.  I kept thinking of Cycle Redundancy Check LOL.